# Powershell: write XML to file

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm working with XML files for the first time in PowerShell. I have a simple script that fails. I need to get XML content using web-request and then save it to a folder for later processing.

Here is the code:

```
$IP = 8.8.8.8
$ipgeo = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$ipgeo = ([xml](Invoke-WebRequest "http://freegeoip.net/xml/$IP").Content).Response
$ipgeo.save("c:\ipgeo\IPXML\$IP.xml")
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlElement] does not contain a method named 'save'. At line:3 char:1
+ $ipgeo.save("c:\ipgeo\IPXML\$IP.xml")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (save:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @CodeCaster `System.Xml.XmlElement` does not contain a method named 'save' or 'Save' - the casting is the issue so changing the capitalization won't help

Comment: @arco you're right. `System.Xml.XmlDocument` [_does_ have a Save() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22(v=vs.110).aspx), but they're overwriting `$ipgeo`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Well it *is* giving that error. It is because `.Response` is being selected which *IS* an `XmlElement`, so it doesn't matter what you instantiate if you then overwrite it with something else in the following line of code.

Comment: @CodeCaster My apologies, I thought I was formatting it incorrectly.

Comment: @CodeCaster No, you don't.

Comment: @Mathias thanks. I don't know what brainfart I was having, but that definitely isn't right for PowerShell. Comment removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can save a subset of the Xml document by referencing the `OuterXml` property of the root node you want:

```
# instead of $ipgeo.Save("c:\ipgeo\IPXML\$IP.xml")
$ipgeo.OuterXml |Out-File "c:\ipgeo\IPXML\$IP.xml"
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for the unbelievably fast responses!

Comment: One more question, how can I read the XML file that I just wrote? I tried: $ipgeo = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content c:\ipgeo\IPXML\$IP.xml), but that returned nothing.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to use: $ipgeo = ([System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content c:\ipgeo\IPXML\$IP.xml)).Response